# Lookup row number based on multiple criteria - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to work out how to select the correct dept from the following range for a given person on a given day

[image]

In cell H2 I would like to add a formula that can be dragged down that will return which department that person was in on that date.

I have managed to work out how to do this with an exact match...

```
 {=INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(1,(F2=D2:D6)*(G2=A2:A5),0))}
```

The above array formula works if the start date is exactly the same as the report date but I am struggling to figure out how to amend this to find where the report date is between the start date and end date. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but try

`=INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(1,(F2=D2:D6)*(G2>=A2:A5)*(G2<=B2:B5),0))`

entered as an array formula.

Comment: Of course, 2 criteria for less than end date and greater than start date. Brilliant. I just made the references absolute so I could copy down. Thank you